# How to get valid image data from HTML in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, image, parsing

This the part of HTML from which I am trying to retrieve an image.

```
div class="image">
              <a href="http://www.web.com/EN/105/News/10228/"><img src="/images/cache/360x295/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000007796.jpg" width="360" height="295" alt=" (photo: )" /></a>
                         </div>
```

I can separately get "href" and "img src" values but none of them are the link that would let me reach the  image. The valid link would be `http://www.web.com` plus img src value. I thought to append the string: http://www.web.com to img src but couldn't figure out how to do it and not sure that this is the right approach. So, what I am trying to get is `http://www.web.com/images/cache/360x295/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000007796.jpg`

This is my code through which I am parsing the HTML data:

```
-(void) fethchData

{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.web.com/"];
    NSString *strin=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:strin error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];

NSArray *imageNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];

    for (HTMLNode *imageNode in imageNodes) {
        if ([[imageNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
            HTMLNode *aNode = [imageNode firstChild];
            HTMLNode *imgNode = [aNode nextSibling];
            HTMLNode *imNode = [imgNode firstChild];
             NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"] relativeToURL:url];
        NSLog(@"%@", imageURL);

        } 
    }



}
```

This is the output: `/images/cache/360x295/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000007653.jpg -- http://www.web.ge/`

I need to see `http://www.web.ge/` first and then the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[imNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"] relativeToURL:theURLFromWhichYouDownloadedThisHTML];
```

Update: if you feel you must have an absolute URL object, you could follow the above with:

```
imageURL = [imageURL absoluteURL];
```

Comment: It worked but I see src value first and then base url. I need the other way round. Thanks.

Comment: /images/cache/360x295/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000007653.jpg -- http://www.website.com/   I need http://www.website.com/ first.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the new code, with logging of both arguments to `+URLWithString:relativeToURL:` and the result.

Comment: OK, I see what it's doing. That's how `NSURL` describes itself when it's a relative URL. Just ask it for its `absoluteURL`.

Comment: (You could also just use the URL as-is, if you're going to download it or the like. It's a valid, complete URL for the image you want.)

Comment: So, you mean /images/cache/360x295/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000007653.jpg -- website.com can be used even though the beginning of the url is at the end?

Comment: I couldn't fit absoluteURL in the code. Can you tell me how to use it. Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't use that string. I mean, you can use the `NSURL` object in code which accepts those, such as `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`.